# How to prevent standard user select one of the data from combo box using vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the code following to load record from database into the combo box :

```
    Private Sub loadcmbReason()
        Dim strLeavetype As String = "SELECT leave_type,leave_code FROM leave_types WHERE others = 'Y' AND `status` = 'Y' ORDER BY id ASC"

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            myconn.OpenConnection()
            myconn.FillDataTable(dt, strLeavetype)
            myconn.CloseConnection()

            cmbReason.TextField = "leave_type"
            cmbReason.ValueField = "leave_code"
            cmbReason.DataSource = dt
            cmbReason.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            myconn.CloseConnection()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I have two type of user which Admin and Standard User. My problem is I want to make standard user will get an error when they select this one data from column `leave_type` which is `SPECIAL LEAVE` when they click `btnSubmit`.

Here is code for `btnSubmit` :

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        If ErrorFree() = True Then
            If User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
                If InsertDetails(lblhdddnuserid.Text, lblhddnEmployeedeptid.Text) = 1 Then
                    DisplayMessage("success", "Done", "External Work Duty Details succesfully inserted!")
                    LoadEmployeeByuserid(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)
                End If
            Else
                If InsertDetails(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey, lblhddnEmployeedeptid.Text) = 1 Then
                        DisplayMessage("success", "Done", "External Work Duty Details succesfully inserted!")
                        LoadEmployeeByuserid(Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey)
                    End If
                End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Code for the `ErrorFree()`

```
    Private Function ErrorFree() As Boolean
        If lblEmpNO.Text = "" Then
            DisplayMessage("error", "ERROR", "Please Select Employee No!")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If lblemployeename.Text = "" Then
            DisplayMessage("error", "ERROR", "Please Select Employee No!")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If lbldepartment.Text = "" Then
            DisplayMessage("error", "ERROR", "Please Select Employee No!")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If cmbReason.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            DisplayMessage("error", "ERROR", "Please Select The Reason!")
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
      Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't be a much cleaner solution to change the strLeavetype based on User.IsInRole and filter the available options and thus preventing Standard users picking invalid options in the first place?

Comment: Prevention is almost always better than cure. I have to agree with Hursey. If a user can't select an option then don't even present them with that option in the first place. Would you be annoyed if you were provided with an option and then, when you chose it, were told that you couldn't? When that happens to you, don't you think "why did they put it there in the first place, lazy developers"?

Comment: thank you! that's actually a good idea.

Comment: yes correct according to Hursey,  when u load leave type in combo box, load data only Admin or Standard user leave based on user selection at first.Why u load all type leaves at once ?